# Automatically infering types for a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a React TypeScript component that accepts an array as input. The component displays the input by mapping over it and rendering each object in the array as a Card. Each object consists of multiple properties, including a `data` property that can have different types for each object in the array.

If I pass an array of objects with different `data` types to the component, the TypeScript compiler infers the type of `data` based on the first object in the array, which can lead to type errors when rendering subsequent objects with different `data` types.

Here is the code for the Card component and a sample usage in a ListPrintingPoints component:

```js
import {
  forwardRef,
  ReactNode,
  HTMLAttributes,
  Ref,
  ForwardedRef,
  ElementType,
} from 'react';

export type Tabulated<T> = {
  header?: string;
  data: T;
  dataContainer?: ElementType;
  formatter?: (data: T) => ReactNode;
  isVisible?: boolean;
};

export interface CardProps<T> extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  readonly tabulated: Tabulated<T>[];
  readonly className?: string;
}

const CardContainer = <T,>(
  { tabulated, className = '', ...rest }: CardProps<T>,
  ref: Ref<HTMLElement>
) => {
  return (
    <article
      className={`flex flex-col sm:flex-row bg-white rounded-md p-4 gap-2 ${className}`}
      ref={ref}
      {...rest}
    >
      {tabulated.map(
        ({
          header,
          data,
          dataContainer: Container = 'p',
          formatter,
          isVisible = true,
        }) => (
          <>
            {isVisible && (
              <div className={`${header ? 'flex-1' : 'w-fit'}`}>
                {header && (
                  <h3 className="text-sm sm:text-base leading-6 font-normal text-gray-500 mb-1">
                    {header}
                  </h3>
                )}
                <Container
                  className={`${
                    Container === 'p'
                      ? 'text-sm sm:text-base leading-normal font-bold text-gray-70 w-full'
                      : 'w-full'
                  } ${!header ? 'h-full' : ''} `}
                >
                  {!data && !formatter && '-'}
                  {data && !formatter && (data as ReactNode)}
                  {data && formatter && formatter(data)}
                </Container>
              </div>
            )}
          </>
        )
      )}
    </article>
  );
};

export const Card = forwardRef(CardContainer) as <T>(
  props: CardProps<T> & {
    ref?: ForwardedRef<HTMLElement>;
  }
) => ReturnType<typeof CardContainer>;

type PrintingPoint = {
   serialCode: string;
   macs: {
      ethMac: string;
      wlanMac: string;
   }
}

const printingPoints: PrintingPoint[] = [
    {
      serialCode: 'oDYxPieXt98mPuDVp2GF'
      macs: {
       ethMac: 'B7:68:83:5E:B7:27'
       wlanMac: '6A:AF:90:44:92:9E'
      }
    },
    {
      serialCode: 'MjGxwY9uEgHvtq78HHsH'
      macs: {
       ethMac: '9A:66:00:F2:B9:03'
       wlanMac: '0D:C3:75:1B:4C:A6'
      }
    }
]

interface ListPrintingPointsProps {
    printingPoints: PrintingPoints[]
}

const ListPrintingPoints = ({ printingPoints }: ListPrintingPointsProps) => {
   return ( 
       <ul>
           {printingPoints.map((printingPoint) => (
            <li key={printingPoint.serialCode}>
              <Card
                tabulated={[
                  {
                    header: 'Serial Code',
                    data: printingPoint.serialCode,
                  },
                  {
                    header: 'Ethernet:MAC',
                    data: printingPoint.macs.ethMac,
                    formatter: (data) => data.toUpperCase(),
                  },
                  {
                    header: 'WLAN:MAC',
                    data: printingPoint.macs.wlanMac,
                    formatter: (data) => data.toUpperCase(),
                  },
                  {
                    dataContainer: 'div',
                    data: ( 
                      <div className="flex justify-end items-center w-full h-full">
                        <button>
                          <ArrowRightIcon className="stroke-2 text-brand-500 w-5 h-5" />
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    ),
                  },
                ]}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
    )
```

To avoid this issue, is it possible to infer the type of the `data` property separately for each object in the array?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here might be composition - is it possible to restructure the components? From what I gather, you want to pass `JSX.Element | string` as data right?
Maybe a good idea would be to split the two into different properties, one of type `string` and one of type `JSX.Element`.

Another thing to try, is to define the `tabulated` prop contents as a constant, and use it as

```
const tabulated = yourData as const
```

But that's only if you're not planing to mutate the data.

Comment: Hi @michalstruck, not really. What I really want is to the `data` prop to be flexibe enough to deal with any kind of data. The format of the Tabulated type will be always the same, the only that will change is the `data` prop which represents the data to be rendered.

For example, I could render:

```
<Card tabulated={[
    {
         header: 'Name'
         data: 'Leonardo'
    },
    {
         header: 'Birthday'
         data:  new Date('04/22/1960')
         format: (data) => `Was born in ${data.getDay()/data.getMonth()/data.getYear()}`
    }
]}/>
```

Comment: Did you try `as const`?